# Reopened topics don't draw attention

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

Recently, I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64043157/10600811) and it was closed because it seemed I was asking for a recommendation. I improved it so the question was reopened. However, after reopening, my topic went almost inactive. This happened for me in some other topics also.

Doesn't Stack Overflow show reopened topics in "Top Questions"? As a user who doesn't have much reputation to spare on bounty, how should I redraw more attention to my topic?

Comment: You do have enough reputation for a bounty. If your question is that important to you spend some. What else are you going to use it for?

Comment: The lesson to learn from that is: You have to get questions right in 1st place, reopening is just a fallback mechanism to give you a chance for improvement.

Comment: You should really include the code you have in the question directly.

Comment: @BDL I put a link to my code in that topic. The code was somewhat long so I just put a link to keep focus on pictures and main problem.

Comment: @AmirSinaMashayekh: You have to include the code in the question directly. If it is too long for the question, then you have to cut it down to a minimal reproducible example. Linking to some off-site resource is not enough (but can be used in addition to the included code).

Comment: It is *still* not a good question as it stands. It definitely needs the *code* in it.

Comment: You'll need to come up with a [MCVE]. A nice benefit of that process is you often solve your own issue in the process, at which point you can ask a question and self-answer it (if it's valuable to the community).

Comment: OK. I added a code example. However, I think adding code example doesn't help much to find answer as I think the problem is from GDI and GDI+ and I need a replacement.

Comment: Would you please tell me why you are downvoting **this** topic? Should I include a code example here also? :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, older questions tend to draw much less attention than newer questions. An unfortunate byproduct of this is that questions that are initially closed and later reopened tend to have a harder time getting attention. That's because a lot of people filter by "newest" questions, not by unanswered questions or by most recently active questions.

Some people have already pointed this out, but that fact highlights why it's important to formulate the question well when you post it.

You can always add a bounty if you'd like more attention for it now.